# finding largest alphabetized substring with python, can't get the last letter in string

Tags: python

I'm trying to find the largest alphabetized sub-string of a given string. The following code works for everything except if the last letter in the string is also part of sub-string.  I realize its because in my for loop if I have:

```
for i in range(index, (len(s) -1))
```

The length of the string being evaluated is truncated this way. If I just use

`len(s)`

I get the error:

```
IndexError: string index out of range
```

I'm two days into learning Python and we are practicing loops, this is the entire code I came up with to solve finding the sub-string: (the grader provides the input variable 's')

```
current = ''
stored = ''
index = 0

for i in range(index, (len(s) - 1)):
    if s[i] <= s[i + 1]:
        current += s[i]
        if len(stored) < len(current):
            stored = current
    elif s[i] > s[i + 1]:
        current += s[i]
        if len(stored) < len(current):
            stored = current
        index += 1
        current = ''
        print("reset")

print("Largest alphabetized string is : " + stored)
```

I've tried slicing instead of using range(), but get other index errors. I think I've exhausted all the tools they have given us so far and now I'm stuck. I'm sure its not very elegant, so other tips are welcome.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close, but there are a few small things.

1. You are trying to see if the letter at the current position is further along the alphabet than the next letter. So if you're at position `len(s) - 1`, you are at the last position in the string, and you cannot look at the next letter. That is why you are getting the error message.
2. You only need to replace the stored with the current value if the next letter is smaller in the alphabet and you are about to reset. Hence, the first `if len(stored) < len(current)` block is redundant.
3. You are only using `index` to initialize your for loop. So the `index += 1` has no additional effect in this case.

Thus something like this should work:

```
current = ''
stored = ''
index = 0


for i in range(index, (len(s) - 1)):
    if s[i] <= s[i + 1]:
        current += s[i]
    elif s[i] > s[i + 1]:
        current += s[i]
        if len(stored) < len(current):
            stored = current
        current = ''
        print("reset")
# Check also for the last letter
if s[-2] <= s[-1]:
    current += s[-1]
if len(stored) < len(current):
    stored = current

print("Largest alphabetized string is : " + stored)
```

Comment: awesome! thanks for clearing/cleaning things up. At one point I did have a check for the last letter but I was using the wrong syntax so I couldn't get it to work.

Comment: i just ran it, and it miscalculated on one of the inputs the grader gave. After changing (len(s) - 2) to (len(s) -1) it worked 100% of inputs. That was just a guess to change on my part so not sure if it was a typo in your solution or not. Thanks again!

Comment: You're welcome! Yes that was a typo on my part, just edited it, good catch

Answer (score 1):

> The length of the string being evaluated is truncated this way. If I just use `len(s)` I get the error: `IndexError: string index out of range`

Your `IndexError` means you've hit the end of the string, since `s[i + 1]` tries to access a character one position too far. In other words, you're done processing. You can use a simple try/except clause for exiting the loop at this point and getting the result you want.

The following function does this, and also simplify some parts of your code - namely, it uses `enumerate` to iterate over the index and letter of the input string at the same time, and avoids the repetitive parts of your outermost if/elif block:

```
def longest_alph_substring(s):
    current = ''
    stored = ''
    for index, letter in enumerate(s):
        current += letter
        if len(stored) < len(current):
            stored = current
        try:
            if letter > s[index+1]:
                current = '' 
        except IndexError:
            return stored

s = 'abcdwqasdmabcdefghijklqaaaaaaaaaaa'
print(longest_alph_substring(s))  # prints 'abcdefghijklq'
```

Comment: cool thanks! that does seem much more concise. I accepted the other answer just because it still only deals with what I have learned so far, but will definitely be using this.

Comment: Don't sweat it, glad I could help :-)